# Conditional import of Java Vector API

Tags: java, simd, conditional-compilation

I am playing around with Vector API in JDK 17.

Since it is not available on older version of Java, I wonder if it is possible to conditionally import it. So that if Vector API is available, then Java compiler imports it and runs one code path (the fast one), and if it is not available (e.g. Java 8), then compiler/runtime does not import the module and uses the second code path (the simple one).

And if that's impossible, then how are early adopters supposed to use the feature in any real code without bumping requirement on Java version?
Or does "incubator API" means that it should never go beyond toy projects and benchmarks?

Comment: You probably want a [multi-release jar file](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/238).  There is an example near the end of [the jar tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jar.html#examples-of-jar-command-syntax).

Comment: @VGR, I suppose one can put all SIMD code into its own jar file, and make this jar multi-release. Of course, without conditional compilation one has to write two separate files for two implementations. That sounds like a solution, even if not very convenient.

Comment: Did you end up with a workable solution to this? I'm looking to implement somethig similar.

Comment: @jasonk, no I did not. I guess external codegen/textgen is the only way to go.